# shell scripting -findind the avg of 3 nos

Tags: linux, scripting

While finding the avg of 3 nos
I am writting the below statement
avg=$(( a + b + c))/3
echo "the avg is:"$avg
for a=7 b=7 c= 10
It is not printing the value of avg

Answer (score 0):

revise to:

```
avg=$(((a + b + c) / 3))
echo "the avg is: " $avg
```

---

as a completed bash example:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=7
b=7
c=10
avg=$(((a + b + c) / 3))
echo "the avg is:" $avg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the print at the same time as the set, you can use bc piped through to tee and /dev/tty and so:

```
avg=$(bc <<< "($a+$b+$c)/3" | tee /dev/tty)
```